# combination of ngerman and fontspec brings a lot of errors

Tags: luatex

I was using the package ngerman and fontspec with luatex in one document in march 2014 and it worked fine. In the meanwhile, i installed a new arch linux and TeX Live. Now I get a lot of errors like

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex ! LuaTeX
error [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '\e'. l.269      
\directlua{\tempa}
```

or

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \quark_if_no_value:NT. <to
be read again>
```

or

```
! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: attempt to index global 'l3kernel' (a
nil value)stack traceback:  [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\__str_if_eq_x:nn ...}","\__str_escape_x:n {#2}")}
                                                   l.5840   { \  \" \# \$ \% \& \\ \^ \_ \{ \} \~ }
                                               ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> 
= l.5840   { \  \" \# \$ \% \& \\ \^ \_ \{ \} \~ }
```

and it end with

```
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)  253 words of node memory
still in use:    2 hlist, 1 rule, 1 kern, 1 attribute, 38 glue_spec, 1
attribute_list, 1 write , 1 dir nodes    avail lists:
2:12,3:1,4:1,5:1,6:31,7:1,9:2,10:3 !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no
output PDF file produced! Transcript written on test.log.

LaTeX exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Oct  7 22:04:40
```

This failure comes only in the combination of `ngerman` and `fontspec`. What can I do?

```
\documentclass[twboside=false, fontsize=12bp]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ngerman}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily\hebfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Ezra SIL}
\newcommand{\textheb}[1]{\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\hebfont #1\egroup}


\begin{document}

some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: With luatex, you should use polyglossia instead of ngerman: `\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}`

Comment: @flyx Not necessarily; `babel` should work flawlessly.

Comment: `twboside` is likely to be false no matter what you do. I assume you have installed TNR and Ezra SIL?

Comment: yes, both correct. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `ngerman` is obsolete and it's available only for back compatibility.

You should say

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

instead of `\usepackage{ngerman}`.

Comment: Shouldn't one use `polyglossia` instead of `babel` with LuaTeX?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Why? Maybe you're thinking to XeLaTeX, but the most recent versions of `babel` have enhanced support for it. And also LuaLaTeX support has been improved.